# Realm: proper way to handle related, ignored fields

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I have a modell class in Realm with an enum field.
Because enum is not a valid Realm data type, I have to make some tricks to let it persist.

```
public class Parameter extends RealmObject {
    public enum Type {
        STRING, INTEGER, BOOLEAN
    }

    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    private String code;
    private String name;

    // This is the persisted field
    private String typeCode;
    // This is the transient field
    @Ignore
    private Type type;

    public Parameter() {
        Log.d("REALM", "Parameter created");
    }

    @Override
    public int getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }

    public String getCode() { return code; }
    public void setCode(String code) { this.code = code; }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public Type getType() { return type; }

    public void setTypeCode(String typeCode) {
        Log.d("REALM", "Parameter setTypeCode called");
        // Sets both fields
        this.typeCode = typeCode;
        this.type = Type.valueOf(typeCode);
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        Log.d("REALM", "Parameter setType called");
        this.type = type;
        this.typeCode = type.name();
    }
}
```

My idea was to use the two setters to keep the two values in sync. However, when the entity is fetched from database, the setter isn't called (looks like the field is set directly). It makes me feel I don't use the right approach.

What is the right way to implement mapping of non-supported data types?

Note: In this case, I could drop the type field and remap the string value on the fly, which would be awful, but harmless in this case, but I have another issue, where the persisted string value has to be parsed and there it would be not only dirty, but inefficient.

EDIT #1

As long I can't find any better solution, I did the following: I created one more String transient field to store the last converted value and made an on-demand conversion.

```
public class Parameter extends RealmObject {
    public enum Type {
        STRING, INTEGER, BOOLEAN
    }

    [...]

    // This is the persisted field
    private String typeCode;
    // This is a transient field to store last parsed value
    @Ignore
    private String lastParsedTypeCode;
    // This is the transient field
    @Ignore
    private Type type;


    private void reparseValue() {
        if (typeCode == null) {
            lastParsedTypeCode = null;
            type = null;
        } else if (!typeCode.equals(lastParsedTypeCode)) {
            lastParsedTypeCode = typeCode;
            type = Type.valueOf(typeCode);
        }
    }

    public Type getType() {
        reparseValue();
        return type;
    }

    public void setTypeCode(String typeCode) {
        Log.d("REALM", "Parameter setTypeCode called");
        this.typeCode = typeCode;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        Log.d("REALM", "Parameter setType called");
        this.type = type;
        setTypeCode(type == null ? null : type.name());
        this.lastParsedTypeCode = typeCode;
    }   
}
```

In this example, it is an overkill, but the same mechanism is used where the string value should be parsed and the parse is a costly procedure to do.

This works even when the value could be changed (outside this code), but brings in a huge amount of boiler code (and uses three fields to represent one), so I am still in doubt if it is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your `getType()` method like this

```
public Type getType() { 
    if(type == null && typeCode != null) {
         this.type = Type.valueOf(typeCode);
    }
    return type;
}
```

Comment: Lazy initializing is a good solution as long the value can't change. When it can, the solution becomes dirty: you have to add the same code to setTypeCode, too. 
A correct answer, but I don't feel completely satisfied how Realm forces this solution on us: more boilercode.